# How to install latest stable nginx on Mac OS X

Tags: mac-osx, nginx

Can anyone provide some insight on how to install a later nginx than the 0.6.32 in macports? On Linux I use 0.7.55 so would like to have the same on the Mac.

**Follow-up : I realised that I could also build it from source like I do for Linux so that works for me.**

Comment: What version of Mac OS X? 10.4, 10.5, Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check that you are up-to-date with regards to the macports repository.

A quick search shows that the current version there is 0.7.59 as of four weeks ago:

http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=nginx

They jumped from 0.6.x to this version, so you won't be able to go to 0.7.55 without manually changing the Portfile and hoping that any patches apply cleanly, but it's pretty close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! I realised that I could also build it from source like I do for Linux

Answer (score 0):

Was researching installing nginx on Mac, and just ran across [Nginx on Mac OS X Snow Leopard in 2 Minutes](http://www.kevinworthington.com/nginx-mac-os-snow-leopard-2-minutes/)